# segmentation fault on random running instances

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, deadlock, coredump

Below program gives me **segmentation fault(core dumped)** error on random instances. sometimes it runs without any error. The program is just for understanding deadlocks.

Even though I have run this program for about 15 times, I haven't faced a deadlock so far. Sometimes the program runs smoothly(which can be expected) and sometimes it gives the segmentation fault(which is not expected). Why do I get the segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a=5;
int b=3;

pthread_mutex_t mutex1,mutex2;


void* add_subtract(){

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    a=a+2;
    b=b-2;
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);



}


void* subtract_add(){


    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    b=b-2;
    a=a+2;
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);

}
int main(){

    pthread_t thread1,thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,add_subtract(),NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,subtract_add(),NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `add_subtract()` as an argument, you're *calling* the function and then passing the return value as the argument.  In this case you want to pass the function itself... try it without the parens.

Comment: @DesirePRG I think mutex init is also an error in your code, yes gcbenison given you segfault reason

Comment: does it affect if we do no't initialize the mutex?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to initialize the mutex: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_init.html

> The pthread_mutex_init() function initialises the mutex referenced by
>   mutex with attributes specified by attr. If attr is NULL, the default
>   mutex attributes are used; the effect is the same as passing the
>   address of a default mutex attributes object. Upon successful
>   initialisation, the state of the mutex becomes initialised and
>   unlocked.

Comment: mutex1 and mutex2 are global,having default as zero, do they still need any initialisation?